# Problem With Selecting an Element Using Selenuim In Python

Tags: python, selenium, element

```html
<div class="video-options">
            <ul class="video-options-text">
                <li id="like">
                    <a href="#" title="LIKE Video" target="_blank">5 LIKES</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="https://static-video.varzesh3.com/local/99-02-24/Sadat.mp4">Download <span class="demo-icon icon-download"></span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="share-button">
                    <span class="share">Share</span>
                    <div class="hover" style="width: 115px;">
                        <span class="tooltip-text">
                            <a
```

I have these codes and I want to use selenium and click on like button.
I'v tried already with Xpath , Css_element , Id , ActionChains , etc.

None of them haven't work!

This is link : [Video](https://video.varzesh3.com/video/214247/%D8%B3%D8%B9%D8%A7%D8%AF%D8%AA%D9%85%D9%86%D8%AF-%D9%82%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%AF%D8%A7%D8%AF-%D8%A8%D8%A7-%D8%A7%D8%B3%D9%BE%D8%A7%D9%86%D8%B3%D8%B1-%D8%AC%D8%AF%DB%8C%D8%AF-%D9%85%D9%86%D8%B9%D9%82%D8%AF-%D8%B4%D8%AF)

**Update Photos**

[This is "Like" button that i need to click it with selenuim.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KK9RD.png)

---

[The Like's button Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqFd5.jpg)

**The Whole The Codes**

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time


address = "https://video.varzesh3.com/"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/Program Files/Python37/Scripts/chromedriver.exe')

driver.get(address)

time.sleep(2)
driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("span")[2].click()
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_elements_by_class_name("left-dir")[0].send_keys("Email")
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_elements_by_class_name("left-dir")[1].send_keys("Password")
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_elements_by_class_name("register")[3].click()
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_elements_by_class_name("title")[0].click()
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"li#like>a"))).click()
```

Comment: can you add more details about the link? since its not in english. including pictures of what you want to be clicked may help.

Comment: Sure, I just Updated With Photos. Thank you for reminding me. 
@HardBoiledPotato

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To click on `Like` induce `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `element_to_be_clickable`() and following **css** selector.

```
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"li#like>a"))).click()
```

Import below libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

---

**Updated code:** Need to switch new window first.

```
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"li#like>a"))).click()
```

Comment: Thank you but I have already tried , gives me " selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message" error.

Comment: @BamdadKh : Based on your [video](https://video.varzesh3.com/video/214247/%D8%B3%D8%B9%D8%A7%D8%AF%D8%AA%D9%85%D9%86%D8%AF-%D9%82%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%AF%D8%A7%D8%AF-%D8%A8%D8%A7-%D8%A7%D8%B3%D9%BE%D8%A7%D9%86%D8%B3%D8%B1-%D8%AC%D8%AF%DB%8C%D8%AF-%D9%85%D9%86%D8%B9%D9%82%D8%AF-%D8%B4%D8%AF) link the code is working fine and clicked on the like button.If your referring some other link then you need to share that link.

Comment: Yes,You were right man , worked separate, and I updated the whole the code. could you tell me where is the problem that doesn't work there! @KunduK

Comment: @BamdadKh : It is opening a new window once you click on the link.You need to switch to new window first before clicks on like button on the next window.check updated code.Let me know the status.

Comment: Thank you man , You thought me something that I didn't know. I google it a lot and I couldn't find the problem. just could you explain me why we used [-1] in window_handles . anyway thank you again @KunduK

Comment: `driver.window_handles[-1]` switch to last window.So in your case this will switch to second window.